# JavaScript won't include tr- and td-tags in string

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

#### i am trying to insert a `<tr>` and a `<td>` into a table using javascript.

I have a fairly simple javascript-code that prints a string every time I click a button. It's being printed into a `<table>`, but javascript ignores the `<tr>` and `<td>`tags.

How do I make Javascript include `<tr>` and `<td>` tags?
I gave already tried escaping the string in various ways.

#### code used:

```html
    <script>
        function MoreCameras() {
                 document.getElementById("AddCamera").innerHTML += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='SSIDSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera SSID'></td><td><input type='text' name='NameSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Name'></td><td><input type='password' name='PasswordSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Password'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='EnabledSetup[]'/></td></tr>";
            }
    </script>
    <button onclick="MoreCameras()">Try it</button>
    <table>
    <div id="AddCamera">
    
    </div>
    </table>
```

#### screenshot for clarification

[image: Javascript ignores td- and tr-tags in string]

Comment: `table` cannot have a `div` child. `div` cannot have a `tr` child.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

You can't add table rows to a `div`. Here's a snippet using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and adding the `innerHTML` to the table. It may be more approriate to create a row using DOM-scripting, cf [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). Added a function for that to the snippet.

> It is not uncommon to see innerHTML used to insert text into a web
>   page. There is potential for this to become an attack vector on a
>   site, creating a potential security risk.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", MoreCameras);

function MoreCameras(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "ih") {
    document.querySelector("#AddCamera").innerHTML += getRowHtml();
  }
  if (evt.target.id === "ds") {
    document.querySelector("#AddCamera").appendChild(createRow());
  }
}

function createRow() {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  const cells = [...Array(4)].map(td => document.createElement("td"));
  const inputs = [...Array(4)].map(input => document.createElement("input"));

  inputs[0].type = "text";
  inputs[0].name = "SSIDSetup[]";
  inputs[0].classList.add("form-control");
  inputs[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "Camera SSID");

  inputs[1].type = "text";
  inputs[1].name = "NameSetup[]";
  inputs[1].classList.add("form-control");
  inputs[1].setAttribute("placeholder", "Camera Name");

  inputs[2].type = "password";
  inputs[2].name = "PasswordSetup[]";
  inputs[2].classList.add("form-control");
  inputs[2].setAttribute("placeholder", "Camera Password");

  inputs[3].type = "checkbox";
  inputs[3].name = "EnabledSetup[]";

  cells.forEach((cell, i) => {
    cell.appendChild(inputs[i]);
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });

  return row;
}

function getRowHtml() {
  return `
    <tr>
      <td>  
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="SSIDSetup[]"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Camera SSID">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input 
          type="text"
          name="NameSetup[]
          class="form-control" 
          placeholder="Camera Name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input 
          type="password"
          name="PasswordSetup[]"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Camera Password">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="EnabledSetup[]">
       </td>
    </tr>`;
}
```

```html
<button id="ih">Try it (innerHTML)</button> 
<button id="ds">Try it (DOM scripting)</button>
<table>
  <tbody id="AddCamera"></tbody>
</tabe>
```

Comment: +1 for this, you want to use innerhtml to insert markup but you don't want unescaped user input in there, use `text` on the inserted markup after to insert any user generated content

Comment: Btw this answer also makes tbody on every row. Tested locally.  As mentioned in both other answers id should be on tbody inside table if im not mistaken.

Comment: @ikiK well spotted, moved `innerHTML` to `tbody#AddCamera`

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting cell based elements into a div, this is not valid html.
add a `tbody` `thead` and add the id you insert into to the `tbody`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove div and put id="AddCamera" on table. You where inserting td tr in wrong way.

EDIT: 
actually add tbody with that id, that will give you right HTML syntax

```
<tbody id="AddCamera">
```

```html
<script>
    function MoreCameras() {
             document.getElementById("AddCamera").innerHTML += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='SSIDSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera SSID'></td><td><input type='text' name='NameSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Name'></td><td><input type='password' name='PasswordSetup[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Camera Password'></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='EnabledSetup[]'/></td></tr>";
        }
</script>
<button onclick="MoreCameras()">Try it</button>
<table>
<tbody id="AddCamera">
 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @YouriKoeman Dont assume you are so important, I played around with my snippet and corrected it, i even wrote what i have changed. Haven't even read your answer as I had my snippet open.

Comment: @YouriKoeman It worked as expected with just adding id to table it just made tbody twice in itself but it gave wanted rows. I also made html doc on locally to test it. Lay of my back.

Comment: @YouriKoeman I said when you posted an answer i already had snippet open as well as local file, that's why I was late with answer (I don't see whats going on behind). It happened before, don't assume i copied anything. I don't need help with this. And I did felt a bit of hostility in "just blatantly copy my answer". But whatever. Have a nice day.